# JSF FlowScoped direct entry point

Tags: jsf, navigation, cdi, flow-scope

sorry if this question has been asked but i couldn't find the answer.

I've converted some spring beans to cdi @Named and set the scope to FlowScoped. I've done this to fix a problem where session scoped beans were shared across multiple tabs and breaking the application in previously opened tabs.

I've got it partly working but i'm running into an issue with the entry point for the FlowScoped beans.

All the examples i have found use a page with a button, this button has an action which navigates to the flow entry point (i've created a blank bean-flow.xml file). is there a way to enter a flow scope directly from a link or from a faces redirect? I kind of need this for two reasons. Or maybe there is another work around? I use spring security to login and it is set with a `default-target-url="/search/search.xhtml"`. I've got around this by creating another page and just using the below to do a redirect on load

```
        ConfigurableNavigationHandler configurableNavigationHandler =
            (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    configurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("search");
```

the above works but the below doesnt

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/search/search.xhtml");
```

Idealy i would also like to be able type straight into the address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/searchApp/search/search.xhtml?searchcriteria=somecriteria
```

At the moment when i do that or the faces redirect i get an error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @FlowScoped does not exist within current thread
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
```

Any help at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try to use the DeltaSpike window scoped for this? https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#Scopes

Comment: Thanks a million Kukeltje. That seems to work straight out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to (ab)use a scope for which it was not directly meant to be used. Using the [Deltaspike `@WindowScoped`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#Scopes) is what you should use. It creates a scope per browser window **or tab**